# Need to fire a rule from eclipse that s ceated in drools guvnor

Tags: java, drools, drools-guvnor

Though I am able to fire rules from eclipse those are created inside the project but I am not able to fire a rule thay is being created in drools guvnor after deploying its pojo model? Does my approach right? any suggestion regarding my approach????

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a KnowlegdeAgent, this allows you to create a kbase from a compiled package in guvnor.  http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.5.0.Final/drools-guvnor-docs/html/ch09.html#d0e3433

Alternatively, you can download the rule files from guvnor using a changeset and hardcoding the url there, like for example:
https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/5.4.0.Final/jbpm-test/src/main/java/org/jbpm/test/JbpmJUnitTestCase.java#L213

Kris